# How to receive response from Zoho Sign Webhook

Tags: webhooks, payload, zoho

I am able to hit my call back function from Zoho Sign webhook. But I am not able to figure out how can I receive the response that Zoho Sign sends to my callback URL. Their documentation: https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#webhook-management

Below is my sample code that I am using to confirm that callback function is hit. It saves a sample data to DB to confirm it is being hit. But the response I am not being able to catch hold of. This is their help documentation that guides on the same, but that misses a working sample. https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/webhooks-for-zoho-sign

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Callback()
        {
            using (var context = new ZohoApiTestEntities())
            {
                var rowDetails = new tblWebhook();
                rowDetails.PhoneNo = "7978704767";
                //rowDetails.Notes1 = jsonObj.ToString();
                context.tblWebhooks.Add(rowDetails);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Comment: I tried to get all the responses in PHP using $_POST and $_GET, still i got nothing from the response. It's weird that they don't provide a clear documentation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a lot of hits and trials, this code worked for me. It's bad that after a lot of follow-up and calls with the Zoho team, I did not receive any help from them for many days.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Callback()
{
    string rawBody = GetDocumentContents(Request);
    dynamic eventObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawBody);
    using (var context = new ZohoApiTestEntities())
    {
        var rowDetails = new tblWebhook();
        rowDetails.PhoneNo = "*********";
        //eventObj comes in JSOn format with two keys, "requests" and "notifications" each containing a JSON object https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#webhook-management
        //you can get your required details like this
        string recipientName = eventObj.notifications.performed_by_name.ToString();
        rowDetails.Notes1 = recipientName;
        context.tblWebhooks.Add(rowDetails);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

private string GetDocumentContents(HttpRequestBase Request)
{
    string documentContents;
    using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return documentContents;
}
```